# Can we access to a react child from a custom composition?

Tags: reactjs, children

How deep is it possible to go in the ReactJS tree? Let's say that we have:

```
function SplitPane(props) {
    return (
        <OtherCompo>
            { props.left }
        </OtherCompo>
    );
}

function App() {
    return (
        <SplitPane
            left={ <Contacts /> } />
    );
}
```

If we want from `App` component to go to the last child (and modify props), we can for example use the `children.map` etc. But as my understanding, we can only go until the `SplitPane` component.
Because `props.children` of `SplitPane` is not defined so we will not be able to dive deeper in the tree. However, `SplitPane` has some child. So is there a way from `App` component to access to those children?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to modify a deep child from the `App` component, you can either propagate a method from the parent to all the children untill you reach the child in question that needs modification. Or, a better way of doing this is using [ReactJS Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html).

With the context approach, you declare the context of the children from inside the `App` component, this will allow the final child component to call on the declared context directly, without the middle components interfering with the propagation of the information.

Your code would look something like this:

```
class OtherCompo extends React.Component {
    static contextTypes = {
        left: React.PropTypes.instanceOf(React.Component)
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <SomeComp />
                { this.context.left }
                <SomeOtherComp />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

class SplitPane extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <OtherCompo></OtherCompo>
        );
    }
}

class App extends React.Component {
    static childContextTypes = {
        left: React.PropTypes.instanceOf(React.Component)
    };

    getChildContext() {
        return { left: <Contacts /> };
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <SplitPane />
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: interesting, but the `If you want your application to be stable, don’t use context. It is an experimental API and it is likely to break in future releases of React.` looks scary.

Comment: I would not worry too much about it, you can just verify that it still works whenever you decide to update the version of ReactJS, and in any case, you can do the props propagation to the children from the parent if you decide not to use context, and that will always work.